# Error when trying to display colorbar using matplotlib library Python 3.9

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, librosa

I'm currently learning to use the librosa library and when trying to display a colorbar on an associated spectrogram, I get an inexplicable error. I'm not that familiar with matplotlib I've searched everywhere for a solution and I can't help but feel I'm missing something here.

The following code:

```
n_fft = 2048 #number of samples (window of performing an FFT)
hop_length = 512 #amount shifting each fourier transform to the right

stft = librosa.core.stft(signal, hop_length=hop_length, n_fft=n_fft)

spectogram = np.abs(stft)

log_spectogram = librosa.amplitude_to_db(spectogram)

librosa.display.specshow(log_spectogram, sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

causes an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'axes'. Did you mean: 'axis'?
```

However, if I remove the line

```
plt.colorbar()
```

I get the following result, which is OK, but I really need the colorbar.

[SpectrogramNoColorBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/froaa.png)

I need this:

[SpectrogramWithColorBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyzhv.jpg)

I tried using the object oriented interface for displaying the spectrogram as in the librosa documentation : https://librosa.org/doc/main/auto_examples/plot_display.html, but to no success.

Please help me.

EDIT:
Here is the full code of my script:

```
import librosa, librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

file = "Audio_ML\\blues_sample.wav"
#waveform
#loading the audio file with sample rate=22050(fine for audio data)
signal, sr = librosa.load(file, sr=22050) # -> signal(numpy array) containing sr*T -> 22050 * 96
# librosa.display.waveshow(signal, sr=sr)
# plt.xlabel("Time")
# plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
# plt.show()

#FTT -> spectrum (FAST FOURIER TRANSFORM TO GO FROM TIME DOMAIN TO FREQUENCY DOMAIN)
fft = np.fft.fft(signal)

magnitude = np.abs(fft) #magnitudes of each frequency
frequency = np.linspace(0, sr, len(magnitude))

left_frequency = frequency[:int(len(frequency)/2)]
left_magnitude = magnitude[:int(len(frequency)/2)]

# plt.plot(left_frequency, left_magnitude)
# plt.xlabel("Frequency")
# plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
# plt.show()

#STFT -> spectogram (SHORT TIME FOURIER TRANSFORM)
n_fft = 2048 #number of samples (window of performing an FFT)
hop_length = 512 #amount shifting each fourier transform to the right

stft = librosa.core.stft(signal, hop_length=hop_length, n_fft=n_fft)

spectogram = np.abs(stft)

log_spectogram = librosa.amplitude_to_db(spectogram)

librosa.display.specshow(log_spectogram, sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

#MFCCs
MFCCs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=signal, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, n_mfcc=13)
```

I am using matplotlib 3.7 and librosa 0.10.0

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug with the amount of code you've provided. Could you please provide a more complete code sample? When I use my own `signal` and set `sr = 22050`, I get a plot with a colorbar with no issue.

Comment: Could you also add which versions of librosa and matplotlib you are using?

Comment: Still can't reproduce your error. What line is your error referring to specifically? Also, if you are running this in a notebook, could you try restarting the kernel and only running this cell?

Comment: The line that causes the error is "plt.colorbar()". I'm running this on Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem was to do with the most recent version of matplotlib.
I managed to fix the problem by downgrading matplotlib 3.7.0 to matplotlib 3.6.0 using

```
pip install matplotlib==3.6.0
```

I got the desired colorbar after doing this.

Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: 3.6.3 works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem importing a file in Pycharm's console window with the following code:

```
import os

import pandas as pd
if os.name != 'posix':
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

...

def create_pareto_chart(df: pd.DataFrame, topax: matplotlib.axes.Axes):
...
```

with the following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\Rober\PycharmProjects\Remora\Utils.py", line 84, in <module>
    def create_pareto_chart(delay_df: pd.DataFrame, topax: matplotlib.axes.Axes):
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rober\PycharmProjects\Remora\venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\__init__.py", line 226, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'axes'
```

Based on the bug report at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25506#issuecomment-1518359815, the issue is lazy loading by Pycharm (in my case) and librosa (in your case), where the submodules are not found. Importing `matplotlib.pyplot` before matplotlib dependencies solves the problem even with the latest version:

```
import os

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
if os.name != 'posix':
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```